# Is it possible to make Key Counter in Python?

Tags: python, types, counter, keypress

I want to make a key counter in Python. For example:
If I click "a" it will print "1", if I clicked next key it will print "2" ...

Can I make it in pygame?

Comment: show your current code, current "game". Actually, the answer is : "Yes, you can make it in pygame. Just try"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pygame you can make a loop that gets the keypress event, and then according to the character associated with the event you can print it. Read the [pygame docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Comment: Hi i made this program, but I have a problem with it. The keypress works only when the window is open. Is there way to make it working when the window is minimize ?

Comment: Pygame only creates events of key presses that were made when then the focus was on the window.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help.